# React Native No BundeIdentifier in app.json

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm creating a react native app with expo and I can't find my ios bundleIdentifier and android package too. It says, that Identifiers located in app.json, but I don't have them.

My app.json:

```
    {
  "expo": {
    "name": "Name",
    "slug": "Name",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```